# C++ Swapping an array of integers passed through an int& parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to swap a couple of integers in the format `int i[2]` using a `void swap(int& x)` function. As you see the function takes an argument of type `int&`. Here is non-working version of the function:

```
int i[2] = {3, 7};

void swap (int& x)
{
    int temp;
    temp = x[1];
    x[1] = x[0];
    x[0] = temp;
}

int main()
{
    cout << i[0] << ", " << i[1] << "\n"; // return the original: (3, 7)
    swap(i);
    cout << i[0] << ", " << i[1] << "\n"; // return i swapped: (7, 3)
}
```

How should I do this?

Edit: The answer CANNOT use anything else for the function parameter. It MUST use a `int&` parameter. This is a problem from Bjarne Stroustrup's book: "The C++ programming language", third edition. It is problem #4 from chapter 5. The problem first asks to write a function taking a `int*` as parameter, than to modify it to accept a `int&` as parameter.

Comment: int& is a reference to an int.  Look into how your code changes maybe with int*.  You may want to brush up on references and pointers in general.

Comment: I do not see why this should be related to Mr. Stroustrup. Removing the tag ...

Comment: Hum, you are right, this was pretty unclear. I meant to signify that this was a problem from one of his books.

Comment: What is the sound of one `int` swapping?

Comment: Looks like you copied the example from the book incorrectly. Do you want to give more details about the book so we could look it up

Comment: Looks like a typo in a book for me :)

Comment: I know it's not what your asking, but did you know you can swap two ints without a temp object?  b = a ^ b; a = b ^ a; b = a ^ b;  That's almost as crazy as this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, thanks to @gf's suggestions, I found a solution :) Many thanks! Please tell me if you see anything not very C++ish in there.

```
// Swap integers

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int i = 3;
int j = 7;

void swap (int& x, int& y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main()
{
    cout << i << ", " << j << "\n"; // return the original: (3, 7)
    swap(i, j);
    cout << i << ", " << j << "\n"; // return i swapped: (7, 3)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A reference isn't a pointer. I'd recommend changing the function signature if you can, but if you're stuck with it, you could do something like:

```
int *xx = &x;
int temp = xx[1];
xx[1] = xx[0];
xx[0] = temp;
```

That said, you should probably just use std::swap instead.

Comment: But, a reference in C++ is actually substituted by corresponding pointer arithmetics by compilers. So, I think technically references and pointers are same except some semantic issues. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @minjang: Only the behavior of references is defined. How that behavior comes about is an implementation issue. That said, yes, all (?) implementations treat references as pointers underneath.

Comment: @minjang:The same only different. One difference is that pointers support operator[], and references don't. In this case, that's a serious difference.

Comment: Upvoted as correct, but it seems like a crazy question.  It's safe to take the address of a reference, but it's not safe to then take xx[1].  Who says the next int must exist?  Not the function signature, that's for sure.

Comment: I meant implementation level, not syntax and semantic level. Yes, semantics are different.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at my copy, the exercise doesn't say how `swap()` should look like. It just says that it *"swaps (exchanges the value of) two integers"* and should take *a)* `int*` *b)* `int&` as the argument type.

As you tagged the question *learning*, the real question becomes:
Why does your `swap()` only take one argument?

Comment: It seemed more interesting to me, although I can conceive that swapping two variables is also very interesting. What would make it more interesting to pass two references as arguments instead of one? Would there be a way of still using only one?

Comment: At least the exercise does not require you to use only one argument, thats not its intent.